# Como usar React Hooks con Prev State?

Tags: reactjs

estoy trabajando con React Hooks y me surgió una duda, como podría utilizar el prevState de this.setState en el hook useState. Nose cual seria la sintaxis correcta, muchas gracias por leer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entendamos el funcionamiento de `useState`:

```
const [state, setState] = React.useState(false);
```

Para utilizar el estado previo del estado en éste Hook solamente tienes que llamar a la variable que guarda su valor, en este caso `state`.

De manera que cuando quieras actualizar su estado y leer el estado previo, puedes hacer algo como esto:

```
function cambiarEstado() {
  // Llamamos a la función `setState` declarada con anterioridad en el hook.
  // usamos el valor previo de `state` para actualizar el estado a lo contrario, ya que en el ejemplo he usado un boleano.
  setState(!state);
}
```

El nuevo estado sería lo contrario, espero que haya quedado claro.

Comment: Muchas gracias Adolfo por la aclaración ✨✨✨✨

Answer (score 0):

Según la documentación oficial de **ReactJS** puedes hacerlo de esta forma, por ejemplo:

**Enlace oficial:** https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#how-to-get-the-previous-props-or-state

```
function Counter() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  const prevCount = usePrevious(count);
  return <h1>Now: {count}, before: {prevCount}</h1>;
}

function usePrevious(value) {
  const ref = useRef();
  useEffect(() => {
    ref.current = value;
  });
  return ref.current;
}
```